# Reticulate wrongly translating values of a column

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, reticulate

Right now I'm working in a .Rmd file and using `reticulate` so I can combine both Python and R chunks.

Initially, I'm getting a dataframe like this one below.

```
id    device     sessions
1     mobile     40
2     desktop    61
3     desktop    55
4     mobile     24
```

Afterwards I'm converting it into an R object this way

```
df <- py$df
```

Additionally, I have to say that once having completed this last step, apparently nothing looks wrong when I display it by running `knitr::kable(df)`

But when in following R chunks I'm trying to continue working with this data, I'm not being able to keep on with my work because at that point my data look like follows:

```
id    device     sessions
1     <chr [1]>  40
2     <chr [1]>  61
3     <chr [1]>  55
4     <chr [1]>  24
```

What causes this weird translation and how could I fix it so the dataframe in R could fit what I got originally in Python?

Comment: i tried using this on rmd, but couldn't reproduce the issue.  I was able to get the expected output exactly like you showed in the input with `kable`.  Could be related to package versions

Comment: I would suggest to check the `str(df)` before doing the `kable(df)`